# Difference between Media and Asset module

Tags: 7, media

Today I saw a "new" module: [Asset](http://drupal.org/project/asset).

It looks interesting but I don't understand the difference between this module and the [Media](http://drupal.org/project/media) module, in the 7-2.x version.

Could someone help me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looking at [this issue](http://drupal.org/node/1673750) in the media module issue queue, the main technical difference (apart from UI) would be that the Asset module creates its own entity while Media uses the core managed_files API. In other words: Asset is 'an island' and other modules must specifically support Asset module. Integration with media module is easier because it uses core infrastructure.

There actually is a [request](http://drupal.org/node/1673800) to merge parts of Asset & Media code.

I took the module for a quick spin, it looks pretty easy but less flexible then the media module. However, I always found the media module configuration very complicated (file styles) because of its flexibility probably.